# redirecting URL with .htaccess not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Trying to do a simple URL rewrite with .htaccess but it does not seem to be working.

Want to access http://www.example.com/shop/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=11

using the URL http://www.example.com/MyGreatClub2013

This is what I have in my .htaccess which is stored at the www.example.com root level

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/MyGreatClub2013$ /shop/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=11 [NC,L]
```

Am I doing something stupidly wrong?

Comment: RewriteRules in 'per-directory' context (like in `.htaccess` have the leading slash removed (that slash is at the end of the host string). They have the query string removed too in case you are going to mess with that.

Answer (score 2):

Remove leading slash:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^MyGreatClub2013/?$ /shop/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=11 [NC,L,QSA]
```

mod_rewrite rules when used in `.htaccess` don't match leading forward slash as .htaccess is per directory.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a decent guide: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml

Hope it helps.

Comment: A specific question should have a specific answer, not just a general "read the manual" comment. While that guide looks useful, a link to the part that deals with *this* question would [be much better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72000/should-there-be-a-policy-about-one-link-only-answers).